# Using switch statement with UITextfield Int

Tags: swift

Im am trying to convert UITextfield string into an Integar and then using a switch statement to perform a range check

Already converted the textfield string value into an integer and then implemented the value in the Switch statement

```
@IBOutlet weak private var load1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak private var load2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak private var load3: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var SS: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       var number1 = String(Int(load1.text!)!)
        var number2 = String(Int(load2.text!)!)
        var number3 = String(Int(load3.text!)!)


            switch number1 {
        case 10...33:
            print("success")
        case 66...77:
            print("success")
        case 103...109:
            print("success")
        default:
            print("failure")
        }
```

Getting an error called Expression pattern of type 'ClosedRange' cannot match values of type 'Int?'

This is even though the string value is already converted into a Integer

Comment: Is that your real code? Your `number1` is a *String* and would cause a slightly different error message.

Comment: It is coverted into a integer.

Comment: `var number1 = String(Int(load1.text!)!)`  converts the text to an integer and then to a string.

Comment: Then how to i convert it to an integer ?

Comment: It's quite obvious that `Int(load1.text!)` converts to integer.